# vimeo api 401 invalid signature

Tags: php, vimeo, vimeo-api

I have an app based on vimeo php API and it works well with my old vimeo account where every vimeo app has an "Oauth2" tab in settings which I use in php api calls. It works fine.

[image]

However if I create a new vimeo account and create a vimeo app under that account the "Oauth2" tab is gone and only "Authentication" tab appears. I can find the keys under this tab as well `Client identifier`, `Client secrets`, but my php app throws 401 Invalid signature error.

[image]

What can be the problem?

Comment: zZZzzZZz forever alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OAuth1 only works on the Advanced API, which has been deprecated. Later this year we will announce a shutdown date.

New users do not have the ability to use the Advanced API.